# Rolling update in Docker Swarm across services with health check

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am currently attempting a Kafka cluster deployment in Docker Swarm. Kafka does not work with the *replica* feature of Swarm because each Kafka broker (node) needs to be configured and reachable individually (i.e. no load balancer in front of it). Therefore, each broker is configured as an individual service with *replicas=1*, e.g. *kafka1, kafka2* and *kafka3* services.

Every now and then the configuration or image for the Kafka brokers will need to be changed via a *docker stack deploy* (done by a person or CI/CD pipeline). Then Swarm will recreate all containers simultaneously and as a result, the Kafka cluster is temporarily unavailable, which is not acceptable for a critical piece of infrastructure that is supposed to run 24/7. And I haven't even mentioned the Zookeeper cluster underneath Kafka yet, for which the same applies.

The desired behavior is that Swarm recreates the container of the *kafka1* service, waits until it has fully started up and synchronized with the other brokers (all topic partitions are in sync), and only then Swarm restarts *kafka2* service and so on.

I think I can construct a health check within the Kafka Docker image that would tell the Docker engine when the Kafka broker is fully synchronized. But how make Swarm perform what amounts to a rolling update across service boundaries? It ignores the *depends_on* setting that Docker Compose knows, and rolling update policies [apply to service replicas only](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/). Any idea?